# Prove that convex real functions on [0,1] form a meet-semilattice

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let C be the set of all continuous strictly convex real valued functions on the interval [0,1]. For f,g $\in$ C, define f $\leq$ g IFF f(x) $\leq$ g(x) for all x $\in$ [0,1]. Prove this is a meet-semmilattice, but not a join-semilattice.

My intuition at first was that this is meet-semilattice because a linear function, which is convex and concave, would be the GLB and there is not LUB for all subsets because I could define an infinite amount of functions to have a greater slope, so there would be a lattice with a linear function on the bottom with an infinite amount of functions above it growing infinitely upward. but the problem calls for *strictly* convex functions, so I'm not sure that linear functions are allowed. I don't really know how to approach this or even if I'm thinking about it correctly.

This is an exercise from Gratzer's *Lattice Theory: First Concepts and Distributive Lattices* in the first chapter. I'm working through it on my own, it's not a homework assignment or anything. If it wouldn't be too much of a burden, I'd rather someone gently point me in the right direction to think about the problem rather than outright solve it for me.

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't have meets or joins for arbitrary sets of elements, but to qualify as a meet-semilattice it only needs meets for finite sets or (equivalently) sets of two elements and likewise for joins. So you just need to define the meet of any two functions $f$ and $g$ in $C$ and give an example of an $f$ and $g$ that don't have a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is precisely the opposite, as it must follow from the reasoning below.

I'm using the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of strictly convex function, that is, $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is strictly convex if, whenever $x_1, x_2 \in X$ are such that $x_1 \neq x_2$, and $0 < t < 1$, then
$$f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) < tf(x_1) + (1-t) f(x_2).$$
Now suppose $f,g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ are strictly convex, and define $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ by making 
$$h(x) = \max\{f(x),g(x)\}.$$
For any $t \in (0,1)$,
\begin{align}
h(tx_1 + (1-t) x_2)
&= \max\{ f(tx_1 + (1-t) x_2), g(tx_1 + (1-t) x_2) \}\\
&< \max\{ tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2), tg(x_1)+(1-t)g(x_2) \}\\
&\leq th(x_1) + (1-t) h(x_2),
\end{align}
so $h$ is strictly convex. 
So just define $f \vee g = h$, above.

On the other hand, $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = (x-1)^2$ are both strictly convex, but their meet is not (take $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1$ and $t=1/2$).

---

**Added.**
Notice that in the example above, with $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=(x-1)^2$, there isn't even any strictly convex function in $C$ below $f$ and $g$, since if $h \in C$ is such that $h \leq f$ and $h \leq g$, then $h(0) \leq f(0) = 0$ and $h(1) \leq g(1) = 0$, whence $h(0)=h(1)=0$.
The only convex function $h$ in these conditions is the constant $h(x)=0$, which clearly is not *strictly* convex, and so doesn't belong to $C$.

**Added 2.**
After Rob Arthan's comment, I noticed that $C$ is the set of strictly convex functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$, not just from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, which makes the claim in the previous paragraph wrong, as is points out in his comment.
Here's an easy fix.

If $h \in C$ is such that $h \leq f, g$, then $h(0), h(1) \leq 0$, and since $h$ is strictly convex, $h(x)<0$, for $0<x<1$; define $h_1$ by making $h_1(x) = h(x)/2$.
It is an easy task to show that $h_1 \in C$, but $h < h_1$.
So there is no greatest lower bound of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I agree that it seems to be the wrong way round: the meet of $f$ and $g$ would have to be the function whose epigraph is the convex hull of the epigraphs of $f$ and $g$ and that is not strictly convex in general as your example shows.

Comment: I don't think what you have added to your answer is right:  with your example $f$ and $g$, if $h(x) = f(x) -100$, $h$ is a strictly convex lower bound for $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @RobArthan Ah, You're right! I thought the set $C$ was the one of strictly convex functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, not to $\mathbb R$. I think there is an easy fix.